# Getting orientation of an image JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

I actually try to get orientation of images in JS to add a class to it. It seems to work fine on Firefox, but I have issues on other browsers. It works better with very small images, so I guess it's not working if images are not completely loaded... but I can't find a solution to make it works correctly !
Thanks !

My code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.gallery a').find('img').each(function() {
  var imgClass = (this.width / this.height > 1) ? 'landscape' : 'portrait';
  $(this).addClass(imgClass);
 })
});
```

```css
.gallery {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 width: 450px;
}
.gallery a {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.gallery a img.landscape {
 align-self: center;
 height: 100%;
 filter: sepia(100%);
}
.gallery a img.portrait {
 align-self: center;
 width: 100%;
 filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
 <a href="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-1500-1000-3.jpg">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-1500-1000-3.jpg">
 </a>
 <a href="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-h-c-1000-1500-4.jpg">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-h-c-1000-1500-4.jpg">
 </a>
 <a href="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-1500-1000-3.jpg">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-1500-1000-3.jpg">
 </a>
 <a href="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-h-c-1000-1500-4.jpg">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-h-c-1000-1500-4.jpg">
 </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to do something where you check if the image is loaded first, and if not, add an event listener to trigger it.

You can tell if an image is loaded because it's `width` and `height` will be greater than 0. If they equal 0, it isn't loaded. It may work in FF because it's caching the images, so they're loaded right away.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
function setImageClass(img) {
    var imgClass = (img.width / img.height > 1) ? 'landscape' : 'portrait';
    $(img).addClass(imgClass);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.gallery a').find('img').each(function() {
        if (this.width > 0) {
            setImageClass(this);
        } else {
          $(this).once('load', function () {
            setImageClass(this);
          });
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: `(this.width>this.height)` instead of `(this.width / this.height > 1)` would get rid of the potential DivideByZero problem and be less of a performance overhead. Plus I believe you have to write `$this.width()` and `$this.height()` for this to work.

Comment: Thanks Samanime ! Sound like a good idea, but when I do it, no class are added at all...

Comment: Indeed, changing the math would fix the divide by zero, but it still wouldn't give him a proper answer of landscape or portrait, it would just default to one if they weren't loaded. Since we know it's loaded before checking, doesn't matter which way it's done. Also, I did goof, it should be `img.width` and `img.height`, I got it wrong. `Image` elements do have a width and height directly though, no need to wrap in jQuery.

Comment: @Julien Check my update. I had a goof in the function using `this` instead of `img`.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it, but still same, working only on FF... :(

Comment: Are the others throwing some kind of error? There is nothing about the code above that should be FF specific.

Comment: @samanime No errors... I really don't understand ! I tried some plugin which wait the images load to execute the code, but still same problem !

Comment: @Julien That's very bizarre. If you put `console.log(this.width, this.height)` just inside the `each()` function, what does it say?

Comment: @samanime Ok, I added the console.log. The values are width and height after the css (if real image is 1500x1000 the values show in console are 300x200). So I think it get the wrong values, I need to get original size of the pics, not values after the addClass... Is there a way to get original size of the pic ?

Comment: The easiest way to get the original size is to copy the source to a different image element and then check the size of that image.

Comment: @samanime I find a solution, I posted an answer already, thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0):

I finally find !... Should use naturalWidth and naturalHeight to get original values of the pic.
If someone interested, here is my code working for every browsers.
Thank you Samanime !

```js
function setImageClass(img) {
 var imgClass = (img.naturalWidth / img.naturalHeight > 1) ? 'landscape' : 'portrait';
 $(img).addClass(imgClass);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.gallery a').find('img').each(function() {
  if (this.naturalWidth > 0) {
   setImageClass(this);
  } else {
    $(this).once('load', function () {
   setImageClass(this);
    });
  };
 })
});
```

```css
.gallery {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 width: 450px;
}
.gallery a {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.gallery a img.landscape {
 align-self: center;
 height: 100%;
 filter: sepia(100%);
}
.gallery a img.portrait {
 align-self: center;
 width: 100%;
 filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
 <a href="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-1500-1000-3.jpg">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-1500-1000-3.jpg">
 </a>
 <a href="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-h-c-1000-1500-4.jpg">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-h-c-1000-1500-4.jpg">
 </a>
 <a href="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-1500-1000-3.jpg">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-1500-1000-3.jpg">
 </a>
 <a href="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-h-c-1000-1500-4.jpg">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-h-c-1000-1500-4.jpg">
 </a>
</div>
```